# query with DATE FIELD AND RANGE query using dismax

Tags: solr

I have got a list of resume ID's with the date field and the experience in some range

My queries are working with standard query handler but not in dismax.

How can I check for the date ranges in between suppose 2009-02-02 to 2010-01-01 using solr's dismax query handler

And HOW to configure range queries like minimum experience [3 TO 5] in dismax..
It works with standard handler..but with qt=dismax, it doesnt work..

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding filter queries so the it looks something like this:

```
fq=date:[2009-02-02T23:59:59.999Z TO 2010-01-01T23:59:59.999Z&fq=experience:[3 TO 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

solr stores date type field in **UTC format**, so while querying it needs the date criteria to be in UTC format like 
**date:[2009-02-02T00:00:00.0Z TO 2010-01-01T00:00:00.0Z]**